how to clear error android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
how to clear error i get this error android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class html intent chrome webview error show
Process: com.Heart.Recipes, PID: 32697
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.browser/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared <intent-filter>?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2171)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1805)  

intent coding
        Intent i = new Intent();

// MUST instantiate android browser, otherwise it won't work
                    i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
                    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                    String html = "<html><body>hello World</body></html>";

// May work without url encoding, but I think is advisable
// URLEncoder.encode replace space with "+", must replace again with %20
                    String dataUri = "data:text/html," + URLEncoder.encode(html).replaceAll("\\+","%20");
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(dataUri));

                    startActivity(i);
                    try {
                        startActivity(i);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        // Chrome is probably not installed
                        // Try with the default browser
                        i.setPackage(null);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }


Do you want to open the content in a particular browser or any browser is fine?

You need to remove this line:
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));

Presumably, you have that line there for this reason:
// MUST instantiate android browser, otherwise it won't work

Instead, you need to fix the remaining lines so whatever it is that you are trying to do will work with other browsers. Not only does BrowserActivity not exist on your device, it does not exist in Android, and there is no requirement for a user to have an app installed with that application ID.

@CommonsWare   ree error  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=data: }

@Shagorjhon: The person asking this question is not developing the com.android.browser application.

@SyedGhouser: That means that no app on your phone is registered to handle the data: scheme in the manifest. There is very little that you can do about this, other than perhaps trying WebView or a third-party browser engine (e.g., Mozilla's GeckoView).

my mobile already use chrome how to intent html
